# How to copy docx file in to clipboard using python

Tags: copy, clipboard, docx, rtf

I have a script for formatting code text so that It looks nice in google docs.

I want to automate the process of copying the formatted text into the clipboard so that I can input the text and get the thing I need without having to open the file that was created

I tried looking it up and I found that RTF is used to format text in the clipboard. However I could not find a way to turn this docx file into RTF and copy it into the clipboard.

I feel like this should be trivial problem because when I copy a text from a word file and paste it into google docs it is automatically formatted in the same way. This means that the OS somehow knows how to copy something in RTF format but I could not automate the task in Python